# Bidirectional one-to-may django

Tags: django, api, backend

I would like to create a bidirectional one-to-many and many-to-one relationship in django like:

```
class User(models.Model):
   device = dont_know_what_to_write()

class Device(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(
     User,
     on_delete = models.CASCADE
   )
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django if you define a relation from *A* to *B*, then Django will automatically add a *conceptual* relation from *B* to *A* which you can query. Django thus already has added the relation in reverse. Indeed, if you implement the models with:

```
class User(models.Model):
    # no device
    pass

class Device(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE
   )
```

then you can access the set of device related to the user with:

```
myuser.device_set.all()
```

this is a `QuerySet` that will contain all `Device`s that have `myuser` as `user`.

You can specify another name with the [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name):

```
class Device(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
        related_name='devices'
    )
```

then you can obtain the devices with:

```
myuser.devices.all()
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).